Spring boot 3.3.3 CDS when generating container image with the spring boot maven plugin
I have read through a few posting here but I am still failing to generate an OCI image when building an OCI image with CDS. I have set the properties as mention on the github spring-lifecycle-smoke-tests for flyway, jpa and jdbc. However I still am receiving:
 [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Spring Boot 5.31.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_CDS_ENABLED                 false  whether to enable CDS optimizations at runtime
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_AOT_ENABLED              false  whether to enable Spring AOT at runtime
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_CDS_ENABLED                  true   whether to enable CDS & perform JVM training run
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_AOT_ENABLED               false  whether to enable Spring AOT
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED   false  whether to contribute Spring Boot cloud bindings support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_VERSION    1      default version of Spring Cloud Bindings library to contribute
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED  false  whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED   true   Deprecated - whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]       Spring Cloud Bindings 2.0.3: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Performance: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Extracting Jar
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     [Too many errors, abort]
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to contribute spring-cds layer
[INFO]     [creator]     error extracting Boot jar at /tmp/1725638148724/jar-dest/runner.jar
[INFO]     [creator]     error extracting Jar with jarmode
[INFO]     [creator]     signal: aborted (core dumped)
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1

The properties I have set in application.yml are:

spring.flyway.enabled: false
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: none
spring.sql.init.mode: never

as per the documentation
Is there a way to display what the errors are so they can be addressed?
Using:

Spring boot 3.3.3
MacOS 14.6.1
Liberica JDK 21
Maven 3.9.9

Expecting with the properties being set to values prescribed in the github(sorry not sure if I can post link here) spring-lifecycle-smoke-tests I'll get a successful maven build of the OCI image with CDS

Setting the verboseLogging option in the build-image configuration might give more information about what the buildpack is doing. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/maven-plugin/build-image.html#build-image.customization
